# How final keyword works in Android

Tags: java, android, final

I Know that in Java we use `final` keyword to variables or something else to make its values not to be changed.

What is the difference in using `final` as in the example below?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView campoTexto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.campoTexto);

    Button botaoTexto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botaoTexto);
    Button botaoCor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botaoCor);

    final RelativeLayout fundoTela = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.fundoTela);
```

Comment: Since it's not apparent where `campoTexto` is used, no idea. It might need to be final to be used in an anonymous class defined in the same method.

Comment: no difference at all.

Comment: Prevents you from re-assigning another view to the variable campoTexto.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It is java...`final` key word is always the same either in android or not in android. It depends on what you apply to.

For example

Apply to the variable means it cannot be changed after initialized.

Apply to method means it cannot be overload the method.

Apply to the class and you cannot override that class.

Answer (score 6):

Final only lock the reference. Not the object and method inside the reference.

In Android it's just like the way in Java.

For example, `final int a = 5`, then a cannot be changed.

Final `final TextView campoTexto`; then campoTexto cannot be redefined, but the method inside, `like setText or others`, are allowed to use.

A more comprehensive example is `Final Deque<Integer> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();` then stack cannot be redefined, but `stack.push, pop` and other methods are allowed to use, so the object inside the stack are allowed to change

Answer (score 4):

For variables, the `final` keyword means it is basically a **constant**. In this case, as it is an object, its reference cannot be changed. So basically if you try to assign to `final TextView campoTexto` again, the compiler will throw an error out.